# C# subprocesos y formularios

Tags: c#, formularios, hilos

Al correr un `Thread` cuyo método al final abra un nuevo formulario ¿Este no se mantiene abierto?

```
var thread = new Thread( () => grafica(edad,años));
thread.Start();`
```

Hice esto y si abre el nuevo formulario pero solo por unos mili segundos, apenas y se ve, alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

¿Tendré que abrir el formulario desde mi hilo principal?

Comment: Si quieres que modifiquemos el código que coloqué en el ejemplo de mi respuesta podrías subir lo que hace el método grafica(edad,años).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11995563/6104382) de SO.

Puedes probar usando una llamada `Invoke`.

**Ejemplo:**

```
public static Form globalForm;

void Main()
{
    globalForm = new Form();
    globalForm.Show();
    globalForm.Hide();
    // Spawn threads here
}

void ThreadProc()
{
    myForm form = new myForm();
    globalForm.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() {
        form.Text = "my text";
        form.Show();
    });
}
```

La llamada `Invoke` le dice al formulario "Por favor, ejecute este código en su hilo en lugar del mío." A continuación, podes realizar cambios en la interfaz de usuario de WinForms desde dentro del delegado.

Para más información sobre `Invoke`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx

Deberás utilizar un objeto WinForms que ya existe para llamar a `Invoke`. He mostrado en el ejemplo cómo puedes crear un objeto global; De lo contrario, si tiene otros objetos de Windows, puedes utilizarlos.